# Postgresql : download schema at the same time while showing using \d+ <table_name> command?

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu, database-schema

I know to download schema one can use `pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -d crm -h localhost -s > exp.dmp` . However this does not give proper information about foreign keys, which tables are referring the current table.

But when I use `\d+ <table_name>` , it shows all info about the db with foreign keys, which tables are referring the current table.

Now the question is how to download this `\d+ <table_name>`  output. I tried to use `\d+ <table_name> > abc.dmp` , but doesn't work. Any command that does this?

P.S. I work on Linux(Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See psql help (`\?`):

```
\o [FILE]              send all query results to file or |pipe
```

Example:

```
test=# \o a_table.txt
test=# \d+ a_table
test=# \q
$ more a_table.txt
```

PS. Use `\o` without a parameter to turn it off.

Comment: So if I am going thru all 1000 tables, it all will be appended in a file or replaced by new table definition?

Comment: New results will be appended to the file untill you use `\o` again.